# Span multiple columns with RecyclerView

Tags: android, layout-manager, android-recyclerview

So what I am trying to go for is having a staggered layout but the first item in the list needs to span two columns. The first two rows are also a fixed height. I have everything working except the first item spanning two columns.

I am using the RecyclerView.Adapter with the StaggeredGridLayoutManager. Doesn't seem like it is out of the box functionality. I assume I can make a custom layout manager I'm just not sure where to start. I have tried searching but I can't find anything about how to get items to span multiple columns.

The image below is what what I am looking for in the list.

[image: Staggered layout]

Comment: Did you ever find a way to accomplish this?

Comment: The first Item always spans two columns. I had to put negative right margin to get the results.
The second item is a dummy item with visibility set to INVISIBLE.

Comment: Is it possible that you share your code about that solution? I'm trying to achieve the same result but without success.

Comment: @DDukesterman did my reply help you? If so, could you please accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, will you please post your adapter code, I'm facing small issue.

Comment: Any luck with the implementation ? I am looking for a similar implementation.

Answer (score 55):

Currently, `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` only supports views that span all the columns (for a vertically configured layout), and not an arbitrary number of them.

If you still want to span them across all the columns, you should do this in the adapter implementation:

```
public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
}
```

<s>IMHO, `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` is still under heavy development and Google wants us to use it for feedback :(</s>

Comment: attempting this - getLayoutParams is returning null. Anyone any luck?

Comment: @JasonVanAnden, getLayoutParams was also returning me null. Maybe my answer can help you.

Comment: Hmmm that shouldn't happen at the time `onBindViewHolder` is called... Maybe you have another issue somewhere else and you are just workarounding it.

Comment: So it's impossible to do it by using GridLayoutManager ?

Comment: Not quite 'under heavy development' as the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` appears to be mostly unchanged more than one year later.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$i cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Answer (score 11):

What I did to span all columns for a vertically configured layout was create new `LayoutParams` and set full span to true in the adapter implementation:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by [ljmelgui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210584/901493) works fine but can be mixed with [mato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27491819/901493) answer for a minor optimization by trying to reuse the layoutParams in case they exist:

```
public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    if ( layoutParams == null ) {
          layoutParams = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```