# Multiple LayoutManager in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I made RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager like this:

[image: staggered]

I need to add some TextView (one colum like in LinearLayoutManager) in above it. It's like LinearLayoutManager in above and StaggeredGridLayoutManager in bottom. Something like this:

[image]

How can i achieve that? Really confused in here, please help.

UPDATE 29-OCT-2015:

I solve it in conjunction with the answer by denis_lor and mato in here:
[Span multiple columns with RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427656/span-multiple-columns-with-recyclerview?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Did you check this https://github.com/karumi/dividers ? You can customize your layoutmanager also.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta. I'll check that

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Looks like it's about customize RecyclerView separator. Sadly, not this. I don't want to change the separator. I want the upper part is some information ( in one column) and the content (in staggered grid 2 column).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is in your `adapter`, you basically rely on the `viewType` and then decide what kind of `viewholder` and `layout` to `inflate`. Here an example:

```
private static final int TYPE_FIRST_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

...

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   if (viewType == TYPE_FIRST_ITEM) {
      // inflate your view holder for the first item
   } else {
      // here inflate your view holder for all the other items
   }

...

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return TYPE_FIRST_ITEM;
        } else {
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }
```

So basically you have 1 `adapter`, 2 (or more) `viewHolder` and thats all. If your `adapter` should have 2 kind of `layout` you use 2 `viewHolder` and layouts, otherwise you use more if you need also a footer `layout`.

Comment: If i use this, it will still in StaggeredGridLayoutManager, which means, the view will be staggered. I want it to be in something like LinearLayoutManager (one column).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, i'll try it.

Comment: Can't change LayoutManger inside Adapter. I put the code to change layout manager into getItemViewType. Error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getLayoutDirection()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Glad you figured out! :D

Answer (score 5):

What do you want to happen when scrolling?

If the top view should remain visible, you can wrap the `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayout` with 2 children: `TextView` and `RecyclerView`.

If you want it to scroll out, you can use `LayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup`, something like this:

```
            layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new SpanSizeLookup() {

                @Override
                public int getSpanIndex(int position, int spanCount) {
                    return position % spanCount;
                }

                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    if (position != 0) {
                        return layoutManager.getSpanCount();
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Interesting hint. Wait i'll try to play with this.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, the accepted answer has nothing to do with the item size